# Dynamically allocating into a 2 dimensional std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a 2d map declared as

```cpp
    unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, Road*>* > matrix;
```

That takes an instance of Road

```cpp
class Road {
public:
    Road() : connected(0), weight(0) {}

    bool connected;
    int weight;
};
```

And I allocate as follows

```cpp
void addPlace(string place) {
    // error checking
    if (placeExists(place)) {
        cout << "Place already exists" << endl;
        return;
    }

    Road *road = new Road();
    unordered_map<string, Road*> *newRelationship = new unordered_map<string, Road*>;
    newRelationship->insert({ {place},{road} });

    // add to network
    matrix.insert({ { place },{ newRelationship } });
    ++n_verticies;
}
```

However, when I call

```cpp
void connectPlace(string source, string dest, int w)
    if (!placeExists(dest) || !placeExists(source)) {
        cout << "Place(s) does not exists" << endl;
        return;
    }
     ...
     if (matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)->second->connected)
```

I get an error: "List iterator is not dereferenceable", which suggests to me that I've gone somewhere wrong with my allocation? Thank you in advance.

Here is my call to placeExists, which returns true both calls from connectPlace:

```
bool placeExists(string place) {
    if (matrix.find(place) == matrix.end()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've broken it down to

```
    auto a = matrix.find(source);
    auto b = matrix.find(source)->second;
    auto c = matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest); // (<Error reading characters of string.>, {connected=??? weight=??? })
    auto d = matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)->second; // stops here
    auto e = matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)->second->connected;
```

My function calls are as follows

```
Graph *road_network = new Graph(false);

road_network->addPlace("Sacremento");
road_network->addPlace("Antelope");
road_network->addPlace("Roseville");
road_network->addPlace("San Francisco");
road_network->addPlace("San Jose");
road_network->addPlace("Davis");
road_network->addPlace("Los Angelous");

road_network->connectPlace("Sacremento", "Antelope", 5); //<-- break
road_network->connectPlace("San Francisco", "San Jose", 2);
road_network->connectPlace("Los Angelous", "Davis", 10);
road_network->connectPlace("Davis", "Antelope", 4);
road_network->connectPlace("Roseville", "Davis", 5);
road_network->connectPlace("San Jose", "Antelope", 6);
road_network->connectPlace("Davis", "Los Angelous", 5);
```

Comment: `matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)->second->connected` This does too many things all in one line. I suggest breaking it apart into multiple lines to help track down where the error is.

Comment: This is a compiler error, right? If you can't even compile the program, then the problem is with the syntax, not with memory allocation.

Comment: You haven't shown what `placeExists` does but on the face of it, you're not checking that `matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)` succeeds before attempting to dereference it.

Comment: The program compiles

Comment: @JonathanPotter That goes for `matrix.find(source)` as well.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes very true although I was assuming `placeExists` was checking that at least (but obviously it might not be). My guess is that `placeExists(dest)` is incorrect.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It looks like your assumption is correct.

Comment: Does it really need to be dynamically allocated?

Comment: Can we see the code that is making the function calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where things are going wrong is inside your `addPlace()` function.
Your code:

```
Road *road = new Road();
unordered_map<string, Road*> *newRelationship = new unordered_map<string, Road*>;
newRelationship->insert({ {place},{road} });

// add to network
matrix.insert({ { place },{ newRelationship } });
```

creates a new road that could represent a link from the city to itself, but not to any of the others. For instance, after your call to

```
road_network->addPlace("Sacremento");
```

your `matrix` looks like:

- "Sacremento"

  - "Sacremento": <Road>

And after your call to

```
road_network->addPlace("Antelope");
```

it looks like:

- "Sacremento"

  - "Sacremento": <Road>
- "Antelope"

  - "Antelope": <Road>

So, later when you try to do `road_network->connectPlace("Sacremento", "Antelope", 5);` it is looking for an entry with the key "Antelope" in the `unordered_map` under the key "Sacremento" in the `matrix` map, which does not exist. So, when you try to dereference the iterator created by `matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)` and access its `second` member, it throws an error because the iterator is not valid.

There are two ways you can fix this:

1. When `addPlace` is called, add an entry to the `newRelationship` for every existing place in the `matrix`, and add an entry to the `unordered_map` of every existing place in the `matrix` for the new place. (This would be pretty inefficient with large datasets, for both storage and processing. Inefficient for storage because it would have to store (number of places)^2 entries, with many of them potentially being unused. Inefficient for processing because every time a new place is added, every single existing place has to be looped through)
2. In `addPlace` simply add an empty `unordered_map` to the `matrix` under the key `place`. In `connectPlace`, if `matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)` returns an invalid iterator (determined by if the value returned is equal to `matrix.end()`), then add a new entry to the `unordered_map` under the key `source` in `matrix` with key `dest` and the value being a new Road object with the given weight.

Comment: This is the correct answer. When you say "inefficient" in (1), you are only implying space inefficiency, correct as it would be O(|V|^2)?

Comment: @mannerofallthings Both space inefficient and processing inefficient. Space inefficient because the space used would grow exponentially with the number of places, and processing inefficient because it would be looping through every entry every time a new place was added.

Answer (score 3):

A big part of the problem is that you are trying to do too much all in one line of code.

```
if (matrix.find(source)->second->find(dest)->second->connected)
```

This should be broken down into several lines. Specifically, you need to make sure any call to `find()` actually succeeds before continuing:

```
auto found = matrix.find(source);
if (found != matrix.end()) {
    // keep going
}
else {
    // print error message
}
```

Personally, I like this solution better than refactoring your `placeExists()` for two reasons:

1. This avoids multiple calls to `find()`.
2. This explicitly shows each access of each data structure.
3. It avoids the assumption that when a key exists in `matrix` that it also exists in a nested `unordered_map`.

Comment: or just use `auto`.

Comment: @Galik Good point. And as Jonathon Potter pointed out, `auto` is cleaner.